# Getting an error while trying to install gat package in tensor

Tags: pycharm, zlib

I am getting the following error during pip install gat;

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I./utils -IC:\Users\sagni\anaconda3\envs\tensor\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\sagni\anaconda3\envs\tensor\include -IC:\Users\sagni\anaconda3\envs\tensor\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcutils/gat_utils.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\utils/gat_utils.obj
gat_utils.c
utils/gat_utils.c(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

I am trying to install the gat package